# error: OpenCV(4.7.0) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "EDSR_x3.pb" in function 'ReadProtoFromBinaryFile'

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, working-directory

Im trying out this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-based-super-resolution-with-opencv-4fd736678066). But it doesn't work as intended.

*This is the Python code copied from the article:*

```
import cv2
from cv2 import dnn_superres

# Create an SR object
sr = dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()

# Read image
image = cv2.imread('./raw_data/input.png')

# Read the desired model
path = "EDSR_x3.pb"
sr.readModel(path)

# Set the desired model and scale to get correct pre- and post-processing
sr.setModel("edsr", 3)

# Upscale the image
result = sr.upsample(image)

# Save the image
cv2.imwrite("./raw_data/upscaled.png", result)
```

But when I run it I get the error message:

```
error: OpenCV(4.7.0) /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/dnn/src/caffe/caffe_io.cpp:1138: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "EDSR_x3.pb" in function 'ReadProtoFromBinaryFile'
```

I'm using *OpenCV(4.7.0)* (the contrib package), I downloaded the "EDSR_x3.pb" model which is on the same folder as the code, and I'm using the input image from [the model's GitHub repo](https://github.com/Saafke/FSRCNN_Tensorflow/tree/master/images).

Does anyone know why it doesn't work or has the same issue?

Comment: Try providing absolute path to .pb file and let know if it helped.

Comment: My bad, the path wasn't the problem but your comment @ivan_onys (thx btw) made me realize I got confused between the c++ and the python code in the article. They are not using the same model (`EDSR_x3.pb` in python and `FSRCNN_x2.pb` in c++), and I downloaded the wrong one for the code I copied.
Though after downloading the good model for the code, it still doesn't work. This time it seems like `sr.readModel(path)` works, but I got this error:
`(-215:Assertion failed) _FX_WINO_IBLOCK == 3 && _FX_WINO_KBLOCK == 4 in function '_fx_winograd_accum_f32'` on the line `result = sr.upsample(image)`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75167763/fail-to-process-upsample-when-using-cv2-dnn-superres-function-to-upscale-an-ima