# fail to process .upsample when using cv2.dnn_superres function to upscale an image

Tags: python, opencv

I tried to upscale an image using the trained model EDSR_x4 but got an error message:

`error: OpenCV(4.7.0) /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/dnn/src/layers/fast_convolution/winograd_3x3s1_f63.cpp:147: error: (-215:Assertion failed) \_FX_WINO_IBLOCK == 3 && \_FX_WINO_KBLOCK == 4 in function '\_fx_winograd_accum_f32'`

The code used to work half a year ago but gives an error message now. The image path is ok, as it can show properly. I updated opencv-python and opencv-contrib-pthon, so they are the latest version. I use macOS 13.1 M1 chip. The version of my python is 3.9.12

The code I used was:

```
import cv2
import os

# load EDSR model
sr = cv2.dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()
path = "EDSR_x4.pb"
sr.readModel(path)
sr.setModel("edsr",4)

# set path
img = cv2.imread(r'test.jpg')

# check image path
#cv2.imshow('image',img)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

# upscale
result = sr.upsample(img) ### error happened here !!!

cv2.imwrite("test1.jpg",result)
```

Comment: can you vary anything in your setup to make this work? do you have any setup where this works, and can you vary that setup to "break" it? this looks like a potential bug or regression. please browse the issues on OpenCV's github repos (main one and contrib one)

Comment: might this be related? https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/23080

Comment: this definitely looks related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74962975/error-opencv4-7-0-failed-fs-is-open-cant-open-edsr-x3-pb-in-function

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and solved it by downgrading the opencv and its contrib package from 4.7.0 to 4.6.0.66. They added Winograd optimization in 4.7.0 and somehow it breaks the code in superres module. Perhaps, you should report it to opencv folks