# OpenCV winograd block(s) failing an assertion

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, tesseract

I am trying to [follow a guide](https://jovian.com/paritosh/data-preparation-and-model-implt) so I may apply an EAST text-detection model, but I keep running into an error.

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/dnn/src/layers/fast_convolution/winograd_3x3s1_f63.cpp:147: error: (-215:Assertion failed) _FX_WINO_IBLOCK == 3 && _FX_WINO_KBLOCK == 4 in function '_fx_winograd_accum_f32
```

I'm too novice to understand what this assertion is for, but from what I have picked up this `winograd` module is speeding up some of the computations. I tried going to the OpenCV [GitHub](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/4.x/modules/dnn/src/layers), but this `fast_convolution` library doesn't exist.

Any idea what's going on here?

```
Python 3.11.3
requirements.txt
-------------
imutils==0.5.4
numpy==1.24.3
opencv-python==4.7.0.72
packaging==23.1
Pillow==9.5.0
pytesseract==0.3.10
```

I tried looking at the GitHub code base, different images, Python 3.10, opencv 3.4.

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75167763/fail-to-process-upsample-when-using-cv2-dnn-superres-function-to-upscale-an-ima